Linux LUKS Encryption - On-demand or FULL in advance?
When encrypting a device using LUKS, it seems to be encrypted "on-demand", I mean, apart from the encryption header data is encrypted "on-the-go" as it is written to the device and all the space left remains unencrypted.
Coming from Microsoft Windows I see a different approach when using BitLocker: I can choose between:

Encrypt used disk space only
Encrypt entire drive

Encrypt the entire drive indeed gives more performance when using BitLocker in Microsoft Windows.
Is there any option like this in Linux using LUKS to encrypt the entire device before use?


Like you said, cryptsetup luksFormat only writes a header. This is for setting up a new encrypted device from scratch.
cryptsetup reencrypt re-encrypts the entire device (converts existing data) using a new volume key. There is no concept of used disk space here, the entire drive is randomized. So this should come close to the "Encrypt entire drive" option.
There is no equivalent to "Encrypt used disk space only" (when converting an existing filesystem). Perhaps it could be done manually…
Once encrypted however, you can use fstrim to discard free space (on devices that support it, e.g. SSD, NVME, VM virtual disks, sparse container files, loop devices, …). By default, this is disabled and has to be enabled with --allow-discards option.
